# Why lstm [Pytorch] returns a prediction output similar to target output but in a reduced scaled?

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch, time-series, lstm

I've been trying to predict the google stock prices between certain dates but when I use the trained network to predict future values I get an output similar to target but in a different scale (screenshots are below).

I coded a lstm neural network using pytorch. The google stock prices were obtained from yfinance library (python).

The neural network is:
lstm:

- input size = 1
- hidden size = 200
- number of layers = 1

The output of lstm is passed to a fully connected layer:

- input size = 200
- output size = 1

Before trainning the network I use MinMaxScaler.fit_transform() to scale the trainning and testing data. Then I use the network to predict future values, and the output obtained is conversed to original scale using MinMaxScaler.inverse_transform()

Nonetheless the predicted output has a different scale that the target output but they are similar.

[Screenshot: plot of y_target (blue) and y_pred (orange)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oQNCS.png)

If I zoom to y_pred I can see the next plot

[Screenshot: plot of y_pred](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xwtfp.png)

What is happening? Why the predicted values are similar to target values but in a reduced scale? What am I doing wrong?

**Code input data**

```
# get close prices from dataset
df_close =pd.DataFrame( df['Close'])
df_close_values = df_close.values 

# normalize data using MinMaxScaler
mmscaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0,1))
df_close_scaled = mmscaler.fit_transform(df_close_values)

# Sequence Lenght 
sequence_length = 25

# divide data into train, validation and test data
len_data = df_close_values.shape[0]
len_train_data = int(len_data * 0.8)
len_val_data = int((len_data - len_train_data)/2)
len_test_data = len_data - len_train_data - len_val_data

train_data = df_close_scaled[0:len_train_data]
val_data = df_close_scaled[len_train_data-sequence_length:len_train_data+len_val_data]
test_data = df_close_scaled[len_train_data+len_val_data-sequence_length:]

# Function to divide data into x and y
def partition_dataset(sequence_length, train_df):
    x, y = [], []
    data_len = train_df.shape[0]
    for i in range(sequence_length, data_len):
        x.append(train_df[i-sequence_length:i,:]) 
        y.append(train_df[i,0]) 
    
    # Convert the x and y to numpy arrays
    x = np.array(x, dtype=np.float32)
    y = np.array(y, dtype=np.float32)
    return x, y

x_train, y_train = partition_dataset(sequence_length, train_data)
x_val, y_val = partition_dataset(sequence_length, val_data)
x_test, y_test = partition_dataset(sequence_length, test_data)
```

shapes result:

x_train.shape , y_train.shape = (2554, 25, 1)  (2554,)

x_val.shape , y_val.shape = (322, 25, 1) (322,)

x_test.shape , y_test.shape = (323, 25, 1) (323,)

**LSTM code:**

```
class LSTMPredictor(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self, input_size=50, hidden_size=1, num_layers=1, output_size=1, bidirectional=1, dropout=1.0, device='cuda'):
    super().__init__()

    # Atributes
    self.device      = 'cuda'
    self.num_layers  = num_layers
    self.hidden_size = hidden_size
    self.D           = True if bidirectional==2 else False
    self.output_size = output_size
    self.dropout     = dropout
    
    # define LSTM layer
    self.lstm = nn.LSTM(input_size    = input_size, 
                        hidden_size   = self.hidden_size,
                        num_layers    = self.num_layers,
                        bidirectional = self.D,
                        batch_first   = True,
                        dropout       = dropout)
    
    # define fully connected (MLP)
    self.fully_connected = nn.Linear(self.hidden_size,
                                     self.output_size)
    self.dropout = nn.Dropout(p=0.2)

  def forward(self, x, hidden=None):

    # Propagate input through LSTM
    output, (h, _) = self.lstm(x)
    
    out = self.fully_connected(output[:,-1])
  
    return out
```

**UPDATE**

I used minmaxscaler separately for each set (train, validation and test) and effectively the scale changed but the result is similar:

[Plot y_traget (blue) and y_pred (orange)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LC9CX.png)

[Plot y_pred only](https://i.stack.imgur.com/txmqQ.png)

Comment: Also, please check if your network has any in-built normalisations. That could be source of the problem. But if you could add some more information? minimum code input data, etc it'd be helpful to give a more informative answer

Comment: I added the code of input data

Comment: Just to confirm, you are exactly using ```mmscaler``` to do the inverse transformation right?

Comment: Yes I am doing the inverse transformation. If I didn't the output would be between 0 and 1, instead the output y_pred is between 37 and 38 aprox.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is this;

`df_close_scaled = mmscaler.fit_transform(df_close_values)`
is first applied on the entire dataset. Then you separate the data to train and test data. This is wrong as it transfer information about test data to train data.

First separate the data and apply MinMaxScalar on the train data. Save this object in a variable and then when you test, use the scalar to convert the values to the model and then the same to covert it back.

I do not see how this can affect such a drastic change in the data. But this is definitely a problem as it is.

I'll inspect the code more and update if I notice anything else.

Comment: I did the changes that you mentioned and effectively the scale increased a little bit but the result is similar (I added another screenshot)

Comment: I think your problem is sorted according to the screenshots you posted. If it's a problem with improving the network let's put it in another question and close off this thread. That way you can get more help.